# What is the rationale behind the decision to have "null as string" return null?

Tags: c#

Is there any compelling reason, beyond backwards compatibility, for:

```
(null as string) == null; //true
```

Comment: Why would it be anything else?

Comment: I could ask you the opposite: why would `(null as string) == null` not be true? What should the value be instead?

Comment: What 'backwards compatibility' are you talking about here?

Comment: Just from your question, I'm guessing `String.IsNullOrEmpty(string)` might help you with something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is vague and essentially not answerable, so I'm not going to attempt to answer it. If what you really want is an essay on design considerations that went into the `as` operator, see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx

And if you are interested in the more general topic of the role of conversion analysis in the C# type system, see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/conversions/

Answer (score 18):

`expr as T` means

- if `expr` points to an instance of `T`, then `(T)expr`
- `(T)null`, otherwise

(and `T` must be a nullable type)

No matter which branch you take, `null as T` yields `(T)null`, for any `T`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part - I'm interested in knowing the design considerations that went into making "as" mean what it means.

Comment: @blueberryfields: Because Java code is littered with `(expr instanceof T)? (T)expr: (T)null`, the C# team evidently thought it would be good to have an operator dedicated to that operation.  It's good to optimize code that appears often in practice.

Comment: That makes sens, but is.. disappointing. Going to the trouble of adding a keyword to the language as shorthand sounds kind of silly.

Comment: @blueberryfields: Most of the language is just shorthand.  `foreach`?  shorthand.  `+=`?  shorthand.  `??` operator.  Constructor forwarding.  Lambda expressions.  `using` blocks.  Generics.  Shorthand is the difference between a high-level language and a low-level one that's also Turing-complete.

Comment: @blueberryfields: Ben is correct. The entire language is shorthands!  Operators are shorthands for methods. Methods are shorthands for fields of delegate type. Classes are shorthands for structs with virtual function tables. "throw" is a shorthand for non-local continuation. The art of language design is *choosing the correct shorthands to embed in the language*.

Comment: Furthermore, *any* programming language is just shorthand/mnemonics for machine language.  Have fun writing code in `1`'s and `0`'s

Comment: @BenVoigt, I think your explanation is slightly wrong when it comes to nullable value types. For example, `5 as int?` means `(int?)5`, even though `5` is not an instance of `int?`.

Comment: @svick: Ok, yes, this is the rule for `T` being a reference type.  For `as T?`, it tests for an instance of `T`, not `T?`.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there any compelling reason

Yes, there is not a single of instance of `System.String` that it makes sense to cast `null` as a non-null instance of. Think of it like this: obviously `null is string` should evaluate to false because `null` doesn't refer to an instance of `string`. Since `null is string` is `false`, per the definition of `null as string`, `null as string` should be `null`.

> beyond backwards compatibility

Backwards compatibility with what?

Let me turn the question on you? What non-null instance of `string` do you think `null as string` should evaluate to?

Answer (score 3):

This is just because a null string reference is equal to null.  If you break this out and show the "temporary" variables, it's much simpler to understand:

```
 string temporary = null as string;
 bool result = temporary == null; // Obviously true still
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression `null as string` evaluates to null for the same reason that `(string)null` evaluates to null: When you convert null to a string reference, you get a null string reference.